# Python urllib request always results in Error 400: Bad Request

Tags: python, web-scraping, https, urllib, http-status-code-400

Thanks for reading. For a small reserach project, I'm trying to gather some data from KBB ([www.kbb.com](http://www.kbb.com)). However, I'm always getting a "urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request" Error. I think I can access different websites with this simple piece of code. I'm not sure if this is an issue with the code or the specific website itself?

Maybe someone can point me in the right direction.

```
from urllib import request as urlrequest
proxy_host = '23.107.176.36:32180'
url = "https://www.kbb.com/gmc/canyon-extended-cab/2018/"

req = urlrequest.Request(url)
req.set_proxy(proxy_host, 'https')

page = urlrequest.urlopen(req)
print(page)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issue but one solution as I found below

1. Is the proxy server which is refused.
2. You need authentication for the server in every case it responds with a 403 forbidden

**Using urlib**

```
from urllib import request as urlrequest
proxy_host = '23.107.176.36:32180'
url = "https://www.kbb.com/gmc/canyon-extended-cab/2018/"

req = urlrequest.Request(url)
# req.set_proxy(proxy_host, 'https')

page = urlrequest.urlopen(req)
print(req)

> urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

**Using Requests**

```
import requests

url = "https://www.kbb.com/gmc/canyon-extended-cab/2018/"

res = requests.get(url)
print(res)
# >>> <Response [403]>
```

**Using PostMan**

[image]

### *edit* Solution

Setting a timeout litter longer it works. however ***I had to retry several times, because the proxy sometimes just dont' reponds***

```
import urllib.request


proxy_host = '23.107.176.36:32180'
url = "https://www.kbb.com/gmc/canyon-extended-cab/2018/"

proxy_support = urllib.request.ProxyHandler({'https' : proxy_host})
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy_support)
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

res = urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=1000) # Set
print(res.read())
```

Result

```
b'<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=5,minimum-scale=1"><meta http-equiv="x-dns-prefetch-control" content="on"><link rel="dns-prefetch preconnect" href="//securepubads.g.doubleclick.net" crossorigin><link rel="dns-prefetch preconnect" href="//c.amazon-adsystem.com" crossorigin><link .........
```

### Using Requests

```
import requests
proxy_host = '23.107.176.36:32180'
url = "https://www.kbb.com/gmc/canyon-extended-cab/2018/"

# NOTE: we need a loger timeout for the proxy t response and set verify sale for an ssl error
r = requests.get(url, proxies={"https": proxy_host}, timeout=90000,  verify=False) # Timeout are in milliseconds
print(r.text)
```

Comment: @dmort did you try more times? Look like 1 time every 5-8 it would work, the other is failing. This means that there is an issue with the proxy. Even if it shouldn't be linked with the initial issue that you asked. Try again

Comment: Yes, I also have to try several times for it work. I agree it is a bad proxy server. It is "free" proxy just to try this. However, before adding the timeout, it never worked once for me, even with other proxies. So that was probably part of the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to work fine without the set_proxy statement, I think it is most likely that your proxy server is rejecting the request rather than KBB.